# How to use datetime in the condtions of a find/count in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to count the number of rows in a certain table by datetime.

More specifically, by a certain month, but can't find the right way to
write the conditions for it.

```
xxx.count(:all, :conditions=> :xxx => yyy)
```

I have a datetime `yyy` to compare with `xxx`, but only want to compare the year and month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work.

```
:conditions => ["month(date_field) = ? AND year(date_field) = ?", month, year]
```

Answer (score 4):

The more efficient way is like this:

```
range = Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month
Model.count(:conditions => {:date_field => range})
```

This will generate a range condition, which, if you have an index on the date_field will be very fast even for millions of rows.

Answer (score 2):

I have a plugin/gem called [by_star](http://github.com/radar/by_star) which you can install using just `sudo gem install by_star` if you have [gemcutter.org](http://gemcutter.org) as one of your sources.

This plugin allows you to do this:

```
Post.by_month("January", :year => 2009)
```

Which will return all records from the `Post` model from January 2009.